# How to display 2 icons in the same line

Tags: css

I have 2 icons on my last cell of my footable, but it display on 2 lines, I don't know how to display it in one line.

I try applying :

```
display: inline-block;
```

to td element, but it didn't work...

Here is my code:

```
<td align="center" class="footable-visible footable-last-column">
    <a href="http://laravel.dev/associations/1/edit"><i class="icon icon-pencil7"></i></a>
    <form method="POST" action="http://laravel.dev/associations/1" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="formDeleteAssociation">
    <button type="submit" class="btn text-warning-600 btn-flat btnDeleteAssociation" id="delete_1" data-id="1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button>
    </form>
</td>
```

Any idea how should I do it???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add

```
display:inline-block
```

to the form.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/7n381z2v/

Comment: ooo, I see, I had to apply it to form not to td ! it worked ! Tx